# Microsoft SQL Server, increasing price by percentage, rounded up

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage

let's say I have a table called products_tbl, and a price column called price. I need a script to update the prices by 3% rounded up, so if the result of a cell is 41.3, it has to become 42. 
Is it possible?

Comment: you can round up the price using `CEILING`

Comment: That's not rounded up... 41.3*1.03 = 42.539

Comment: @lc. I think the 41.3 includes the 3% in this case.

Comment: @Stephen Oh, you're probably right.

Comment: What do you mean by `by 3%`?

Comment: @gotqn, title says "*increasing price by percentage*", I like to think he's jacking up his merchandise's prices by 3 units of price for each 100.

Comment: @KtX2SkD So, he first adds 3% and then he wants to round up?

Comment: @gotqn, I guess?

Comment: yeah, I need to increase the prices in the "price" colum by 3%. But the result must be rounded up too. So yeah, the example (41.3, a totally random number) includes the 3% increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I understood, I'm surprised the question got interpreted this many ways:

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE products_tbl
SET price = CEILING(price * 1.03)

SELECT *
FROM products_tbl

ROLLBACK TRAN -- Because we only answer w/ commits for a fee.
```

Comment: Why are you rolling back the changes?

Comment: @PeterAbolins, there isn't usually an *undo* command for committed changes, so when in doubt, don't commit. If he verified the output to be matching his needs, he can commit it then.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. I tend to assume that people are smarter than they are, in which case the OP wouldn't actually run something that he/she wasn't sure would work as intended.

Comment: TBH @PeterAbolins, I do such things routinely with my own code at various stages, and half the reason I added it here was B House's answer offering both `SELECT`/`UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Test this using select query first if it is achieving as expected,
Use ceiling instead, i assume your data type is int

```
SELECT 
   ceiling(price+ ( price/100*3),0) RoundedpercentValue 
  ,price+ ( price/100*3)      PercentValue
 , price 
FROM PRODUCTS
```

--Update the table

```
UPDATE products
set price = ceiling(price+ ( price/100*3),0)
```

or if there is truncation issue

```
Update Products
set price = ceiling(price + price *0.03)
```

Comment: **Two Mistakes:** First, division of two integers could cause a truncation issue, should have just divided by a decimal. Second, he said round up, not round.

Answer (score -1):

Use This

```
UPDATE products_tbl
set price = floor(price+(price*0.03))
```

Comment: since he said he need to make 41.3 + 3% = 42. I assume what he needs to take the floor. otherwise, he case go for the round

Comment: hmmmm I interpreted his pick of .3 to reinforce the round-up goal, and I assumed 41.3 has the 3% already applied.

Comment: Maybe, or if the requirement is to recursively add the values.

Comment: yeah, I need to increase the prices in the "price" colum by 3%. But the result must be rounded up too. So  the example (41.3, a totally random number) includes the 3% increase.

Comment: so the query might vary upon your complete requirement, whether you want to keep the values as it is, or round the value to the next rounding value or previous like 42.5 need to be rounded as 43  or 42 like that.